# How to insert a HTML comment with dynamic content using Haml?

Tags: ruby, haml

How do I insert an HTML comment whose contents are evaluated by Ruby?

This doesn't seem to work

```
/= 2+2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single line comments like that don’t allow for dynamic content, the string is copied verbatim into the output. You can use block style comments to get dynamic content:

```haml
/
  = 2 + 2
```

produces:

```html
<!--
  4
-->
```

You could also use interpolation in block style comments (single line comments don’t interpolate either):

```haml
/
  #{2 + 2}
```

To be honest, I don’t know the why the two styles differ.